Why does my YOLO model perform differently in ROS compared to a standalone Python script?
This might not seem like a ROS issue but I think it is.
I am currently working on a project that uses ROS to detect illuminated
beacons in real-time with a YOLO model. The model should detect three
classes (“Red”, “Green”, “Blue”). I created my dataset using the Intel
realsense D455 camera to record ROS bags from which I extracted a
subsets of jpeg images in order to reproduce the 5Hz frame rate that
the model will have to deal with in its real-time application.
The metrics of my model are very good (accuracy, recall, precision)
and the confusion matrix is certifying that it never misclassified a
beacon during the testing phase. I verified this using a python script
that I found online, which launches the D455 camera and does the
detection:
Standalone Python script "A":
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
import math 
# start webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(4)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

# model
model = YOLO("beacon_id-v10-vmbeaconid5-train1-1552.pt")

# object classes
classNames = ["blue", "green", "red"]


while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    results = model(img, stream=True)
    print(results)

    # coordinates
    for r in results:
        boxes = r.boxes

        for box in boxes:
            # bounding box
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2) # convert to int values

            # put box in cam
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 255), 3)

            # confidence
            confidence = math.ceil((box.conf[0]*100))/100
            print("Confidence --->",confidence)

            # class name
            cls = int(box.cls[0])
            print("Class name -->", classNames[cls])

            # object details
            org = [x1, y1]
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            fontScale = 1
            color = (255, 0, 0)
            thickness = 2

            cv2.putText(img, classNames[cls], org, font, fontScale, color, thickness)

    cv2.imshow('Webcam', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Legend 1: All beacons being detected with the standalone python script "A".

As you can see, the model is doing a great job at detecting the
correct colored beacons. It even worked when I moved the beacons or
the camera very quickly in all directions. Once I was sure I had a
working model, I created a ROS Node called yolo_stream_rgb.cpp (see end of question):

It imports the “beacon_detection_rgb.py” (script "B") Python module and recovers the “detection_model” function responsible for detection (I used a C++
Python-wrapper called pybind11). This Python script is similar to the
Ultralytics documentation on ROS.

It subscribes to the ‘/camera/color/image_raw’ topic of the D455 camera to get the images, converts them into a cv::Mat object using
cv_bridge

Calls the “call_detect” function that is built using the Python “detection_model” function

Publishes the resulting image to the ‘ultralytics/detection/image’ ROS topic


I can now visualize the bounding boxes directly on Rviz.
Legend 2: Wrong detection published in Rviz

Here is my problem. When running the model through the ROS node, the
detection performance significantly drops. Red and Green beacons are
misclassified, and Blue is never detected (classified as Green
instead). I suspect this issue is linked to how the images are
processed in ROS. I have first tested various color encodings (rgb8, rgba8,
bgr8, bgra8), but since I verified that the camera outputs images in
rgb8, I decided to stick with this format. The detection issue I am
encountering appears to be related to my use of ROS, but I am unsure
of the exact cause.
Here is the rqt_graph if you need it.

C++ "yolo_stream_rgb.cpp" ROS Node
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

py::object detect_func;
// py::object segment_func;

void initialize_python()
{
    py::initialize_interpreter();
    py::module_ sys = py::module_::import("sys");
    sys.attr("path").attr("append")("/home/louis/catkin_ws/src/beacon_identification/scripts/");

    py::module_ beacon_detection = py::module_::import("beacon_detection_rgb");
    detect_func = beacon_detection.attr("detection_model");
}

void finalize_python()
{
    py::finalize_interpreter();
}

cv::Mat call_detect(cv::Mat& image)
{
    py::array_t<uint8_t> input_image(py::buffer_info(
        image.data, sizeof(uint8_t),
        py::format_descriptor<uint8_t>::format(),
        3, { image.rows, image.cols, image.channels() },
        { image.step[0], image.step[1], sizeof(uint8_t) }
    ));

    auto det_result = detect_func.attr("__call__")(input_image);
    auto det_annotated = det_result[0].attr("plot")(false).cast<py::array>();

    cv::Mat output_image(det_annotated.shape(0), det_annotated.shape(1), CV_8UC3, det_annotated.mutable_data());
    return output_image.clone();
}



void image_callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg, ros::Publisher& pub)
{
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try {
        cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg); // , sensor_msgs::image_encodings::RGB8
    } catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e) {
        ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
        return;
    }

    cv::Mat processed_image = call_detect(cv_ptr->image);  // Or use call_segment for segmentation

    sensor_msgs::ImagePtr output_msg = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "rgb8", processed_image).toImageMsg(); // "rgb8"

    pub.publish(output_msg);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "ultralytics_rgb");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    initialize_python();

    ros::Publisher image_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>("ultralytics/detection/image", 1);

    ros::Subscriber image_sub = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image>("camera/color/image_raw", 1,
        boost::bind(&image_callback, _1, boost::ref(image_pub)));

    ros::spin();

    finalize_python();

    return 0;
}


Python "beacon_detection_rgb.py" script "B"

#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import os

import ros_numpy
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

from ultralytics import YOLO


# ====== WEIGHT FILE IMPORTATION ===================

script_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

weights = rospy.get_param("/ultralytics_rgb/weights")
if weights is None:
    rospy.logerr("Le paramètre 'weights' n'a pas été trouvé.")
    rospy.signal_shutdown("Paramètre manquant : 'weights'")
else:
    rospy.loginfo(f"Weights: {weights}")

weights_path = os.path.join(script_path, "../YOLOv8_models", weights)
detection_model = YOLO(weights_path)

# ======= ULTRALYTICS CODE ================

rospy.init_node("beacon_detection_rgb")
time.sleep(1)

labels = {
    "0.": "Blue",
    "1.": "Green",
    "2.": "Red"
}

det_image_pub = rospy.Publisher("/ultralytics/detection/image", Image, queue_size=15) # queue_size=5

def callback(data):
    """Callback function to process image and publish annotated images."""
    array = ros_numpy.numpify(data)
    if det_image_pub.get_num_connections():
        det_result = detection_model(array) # by default stream=False
        rospy.loginfo(det_result)

        if len(det_result[0].boxes.cls) > 0:

            if det_result[0].boxes.cls[0] == 0:
                timestamp = data.header.stamp
                rospy.loginfo(f"Blue beacon detected at timestamp:{timestamp.to_sec()}")
            if det_result[0].boxes.cls[0] == 1.:
                timestamp = data.header.stamp
                rospy.loginfo(f"Green beacon detected at timestamp:{timestamp.to_sec()}")
            if det_result[0].boxes.cls[0] == 2.:
                timestamp = data.header.stamp
                rospy.loginfo(f"Red beacon detected at timestamp:{timestamp.to_sec()}")
            # Need to deal with tensor([0., 0.]) et tensor([1., 1.]) et tensor([0., 1.]) boucle for sur boxes.cls

        det_annotated = det_result[0].plot(show=False)
        det_image_pub.publish(ros_numpy.msgify(Image, det_annotated, encoding="rgb8"))

rospy.Subscriber("/camera/color/image_raw", Image, callback)

while True:
    rospy.spin()

I you have any idea, I would really appreciate it.
Thank you in advance for your time.

Are you sure you are not feeding BGR images into a model trained with RGB images?
opencv natively works with bgr so you should convert into a rgb, look into the function: cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

"@L K" on an x86 machine, the output of realsense2 driver is bgr, not rgb.

"@L K" You should be using the encoding property of the Image msg to discover the format.
